# Touch LCD with Mac Mini

Tags: macos, multi-touch

I bought my first Mac Mini today. I'm using touch screen LCD PL2735M (http://www.iiyama.com/gb_en/products/prolite-t2735msc-2/). When I click on screen, mouse is moved to that place, but no click is issued. Is there any touch settings? (sensitivity, calibration). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This *might* help...  when using a trackpad on a MacBook, tapping does not, by default, click the mouse...   there is a setting (System Preferences -> Trackpad -> Tap to click) that must be enabled.

You might try checking for that...  or something similar, to enable "tap to click" for the monitor (if possible).   I can't say 100% this will work, as I've never seen a touch screen used with a Mac... however hopefully this helps.

[image: Trackpad Settings]

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING: UNTESTED ADVICE INBOUND**

It appears this question was asked on Apple's [forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4883897) a while ago. Most touch screens report as a mouse to the OS, and then require special drivers to do anything fancy. Implementation obviously varies.

The first recommended set of drivers is from [touch-base](http://www.touch-base.com), though it appears they haven't released anything since 2012, so I'd be wary.

I also found [eGalax](http://www.eeti.com.tw/drivers_Mac.html), which claims to work with OS X 10.10 and was released in April of this year. I downloaded, but did not install the .zip file, and their documentation appears very professional and straightforward. Their code is not open source, though, so installing their software may (but probably won't) steal all your credit card numbers or post a digitally-altered sex tape of you to the internet.

As always, you're taking advice from a stranger on the internet who is claiming to not know about the thing they are telling you to install. Your mileage may vary, be smart about what you install and give your password to, wear protection, kids eat free on Tuesdays, etc.